# How to access a variable in another page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So I have this page in an UWP Windows 10 app using C#:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
```

This page contains a TextBlock called tbPageTitle.

I'd like to change the text of tbPageTitle to "bla" from another page, so I use the following code:

```
MainPage.tbPageTitle.text = "bla";
```

However, I get the following error:

> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainPage.tbPageTitle'

I don't know what to do here. I feel like I've read every single Google result.
I found some results to create a new instance of a class, so that would be for example:

```
MainPage mp = new MainPage();
mp.tbPageTitle.text = "bla";
```

But wouldn't that create a completely new MainPage? This also doesn't work by the way...

Comment: You need to get an object reference to the main page, either by passing it into a constructor of some kind of mediating object, or setting it via a property. Note, making pages aware of each other is not good design. 

Alternatively you could use a message bus, there's a really lightweight NuGet project called Red Bus - just send a text changed message and subscribe to it.

https://github.com/mxjones/RedBus

Comment: How do you access the second form from the main?

Comment: Are you trying to create hamburger menu title set?

Comment: @HeySatan I'm sorry, I find this solution a little bit too complex for its purpose.

Comment: @un-lucky The second page is loaded in a frame on the MainPage

Comment: @Sandy Sort of, yes. But there are more variables I'd like to set on other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the answer to Sandy's comment you have an inner `Frame` element in the `MainPage` where you load other pages. So the easiest way to get the current `MainPage` instance is the following:

```
MainPage mainPage = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MainPage;
```

Note that this will obviously fail if you every navigate outside of the `MainPage` and call this line there. Additionally note that objects you are creating in XAML are **not** public, what means that you can't access your `tbPageTitle` element here anyway, but will need to create any kind of wrapper property in your `MainPage` like this:

```
public string PageTitle {
    get { return tbPageTitle.Text; }
    set { tbPageTitle.Text = value; }
}
```

However as mentioned by HeySatan, this is not the most beautiful code design you are creating here. Maybe you could create a method to go to a specific frame, something like that:

```
public enum TabContent { Home, Replies, Messages, Settings }

public void OpenTab(TabContent content) {
    // Set Page title and navigate
    switch (content) {
        case TabContent.Home:
            tbPageTitle.Text = "Home";        
            InnerFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
            break;
        case TabContent.Replies:
            tbPageTitle.Text = "Replies";        
            InnerFrame.Navigate(typeof(RepliesPage));
            break;
        case TabContent.Messages:
            tbPageTitle.Text = "Messages";        
            InnerFrame.Navigate(typeof(MessagesPage));
            break;
        case TabContent.Settings:
            tbPageTitle.Text = "Settings";        
            InnerFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            break;
    }
}
```

Main goal of this method is that if you have a button *Settings* in your `HomePage` you are only calling the following line and all logic to do the navigation stays in the `MainPage` and `HomePage` only has logic related to itself:

```
// In HomePage:
MainPage mainPage = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MainPage;
mainPage.OpenTab(TabContent.Settings);
```

If you don't want to access Window.Current.Content all the time, you could also declare a static method in your `MainPage` class and make access simpler:

```
// In MainPage:
public static MainPage Instance {
    // This will return null when your current page is not a MainPage instance!
    get { return (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MainPage; }
}

// Now in HomePage it's only:
MainPage.Instance.OpenTab(TabContent.Settings);
```